# How to get Connection object and send message using Ratchet

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I'm just starting with WebSockets right now.

I'm working with [Twilio (*voip API*)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client) and I need to make a responsive page that reacts when something happen in a phone call.

For example: The user starts the call and the browser alerts them that they're in a call. If the user hangs up, the status "*in-call*" must be removed.

What I'm not figuring out to do is make a `$client->send($jsonWithCallStatus)` from the server if I don't have the `$client` object? How can I get that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was able to understand your question, you are looking for a way to send json to a client.

And you don't have the client object yet.

To make a client object you would first have to get the client(browser/app) to connect to the WebSocket server. Then you would be able to make a `$connection` object which connects to the certain client.

Then you would be able to assign an ID to this `$connection` object and save this ID in your database or whatever you are using.

This ID could be reused to later retrieve the `$connection` object and send the certain data to that client.

The ID I mentioned before could be the same as a userId, if you have that anywhere.

More information about what you are doing and using might be really usefull to further help you.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, man! I just don't know how to get this $connection by that ID, you know? There's some method to get exiting connections by parameter?

Comment: if you did the entire setup from the tutorial then you have some methods which are using ConnectionInterface conn as a parameter.
Make a list of your likings containing this object conn and an ID which corresponds to it, for example a userID.
Once you want to send a new message to that user you can use the push integration of the tutorial to send push messages over the WebSocket to the user so that only the right userID over the right ConnectionInterface receives the data you want them to receive.